# Pythonic way of accessing a parent's class variables

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I currently have a grandparent/parent/child class structure like this:

```
class A:
    class MatchStrategy(Enum):
        EXACT = auto()
        CONTAINS = auto()
        REGEXP = auto()
        FUZZY = auto()

    def match_string(string1, string2, match_strategy):
        if match_strategy == A.MatchStrategy.EXACT:
            return string1 == string2
        elif match_strategy == A.MatchStrategy.CONTAINS:
            return string1 in string2
        ...

A -> B, C
B -> D, E
C -> F, G

# example grandchild class    
class D(B):
    def my_method():
        self.match_string('String1', 'String2', A.MatchStrategy.Exact)
```

My question is, what's the most pythonic way of accessing `MatchStrategy` in the child classes (e.g. `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`)?
I've looked through stackoverflow and various web pages, and there seem to be three major options:

1. Use `A.MatchStrategy`. The downside to this is that I would have to `import A` in the class file. That is, currently, `d.py` is:

   ```
    from .b import B

    class D(B):
        ...
   ```

   The downside is I would have to add `from .a import A` just to access `A.MatchStrategy`.
2. Use `B.MatchStrategy`. This avoids having an extra import, but it means that in classes `D` & `E`, I would be using `B.MatchStrategy`, and for classes `F` & `G`, I would have to use `C.MatchStrategy`. IMHO, that seems a little messy because they actually point to the same definition but look, to a casual code reader, like they're actually different.
3. Use `self.MatchStrategy`. Since `A` is a grandparent class to all the children, they will have `MatchStrategy` defined. However, this is technically an instance variable, and if it was ever assigned to, then it will no longer point to the class variable.

To those, I'd add the following option:

4. Use `super().MatchStrategy`. I'm guessing this would work similar to #2.

Is one of these ways more pythonic than the other? Are there any gotchas or pro's or con's that I should be aware of in choosing the best approach? Are there other best practices to be aware of?

EDIT
@juanpa.arrivillaga had a good point about defining the enum within a module instead, and then just importing it wherever it's used. I'm using the enum as a way to limit the set of valid options for one of the class's method. I know I could use a simple string but I figured that using an Enum helps with code completion and preventing little typos in the code.

I've added more detail in the code description above. With that, the only use of MatchStrategy will be within the class and its subclasses, so I figured it made sense to make it a part of the class definition rather than a module that could be imported outside of the class and its descendents.

Is there a general strategy for when to use class variables vs modules?

Comment: I usually define these in a separate file like `constants.py` which is not dependent on any other.

Comment: Your code would be more clear if you actually write out the child classes. Also, do you need such a complex inheritence to ask the question?

Comment: The Pythonic way of doing this is not to nest `my_enum` inside `A`. That has almost no advantages. Put it in a seperate module and import it wherever you need it. If you insist on keeping this structure, then just importing module `a` seems reasonable. Why is that such a downside? Also note, in Python, if these are all related, they can just go in the same module. Don't make a. bunch of single-class modules. Python != Java.

Comment: Nesting classes isn't pythonic. Consider putting everything into a package with sub-modules.

Comment: I was going to comment very similarly to other comments here. Even removing the notion of pythonic/non-pythonic, on a readability/usability standpoint, explicitness and better modularization should be the focus here. I echo the suggestions mentioned already by splitting out as much as you can. The "pythonic" part will be the result of the cleaner design decisions.

Comment: Your question about class variables and modules - The question would be more class variable vs instance variable. You have to watch out here as your class variable will maintain its state across instances of that class. So, the question is how you want to manage the state of those variables. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/idjaw/21a3e2002c5c63890a52e84b7865ba52) to illustrate the behaviour of a class variable.